# uml/ocl access to parent class name

Tags: uml, parent-child, ocl

I try to write ocl to add constraint to child (animal), but the constraint must user parent class name (mamifere). I think the first version doesn't work, and I think there is a nicer solution that the second example. Help me please ?

**image for example animal:**

[image]

Comment: You should clarify which child relation you are trying to model. There isn't anything modeled in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

That looks strange. Your first constraint tells (provided it's linked to `animal`) that the type of `aninmal` must be `mamifere`, but `mamifere` inherits from `animal`. That does not make sense.

The second variant does not make sense either. Provided the constraint applies to anything on the diagram, each instance must be named `mamifere2`. So you can have only instances with name == `mamifere2`. Especially strange with a `vivipare2` instance.

I don't see where you model any child relation at all. So I'm just guessing you mean this:

[image]

A child has two parents (well, for humans there now can be more). And there can be `*` children which must have the same type as the parents (so you can't model mules or the like).